# Create a menu hover background color in a specific shape

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown navigation menu and I want to add a background color for it's submenu on hover like on the following screenshot and it should set properly if menu text is long or short. But I don't know how to achieve this for hover.

[image]

Comment: Include code snippet of your current nav menu, so we can help you with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like [this](http://codepen.io/elrumordelaluz/pen/2a82cd62b04e917588da5ff697282bf2?editors=1100) using a pseudo element for each list item.

```
&:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 3em;
  height: calc(100% + 3px);
  right: calc(100% + 1px);
  top: .4em;
  transform: skewX(-20deg) rotate(-20deg);
  transition: .3s;
 }
```

Keep in mind that ideally you have to avoid this *magic numbers* used only for a demo purpose.

Comment: Thankyou @Lionel.it was very helpful to me.

Comment: No problem, glad it helps you!

Comment: Keep in mind that the CSS shown here is actually SCSS.

Comment: yes, it's equal to `li:before { ... }` also use _Autoprefixer_ in the pen, just to write only the unprefixed property.

Comment: @Lionel T, there is an issue ,it will not working properly in local or jsfiddle :(

Comment: You mean the linked [pen](http://codepen.io/elrumordelaluz/pen/2a82cd62b04e917588da5ff697282bf2?editors=1100) ? have a link?

Comment: @Lionel T it will works fine in pen. but not working jsfiddle.net, issues becz of using scss. how should implement thse code in css.

Comment: You could obtain the _processed_ code in the pen clicking the button *View Compiled* in the CSS section. https://cloudup.com/cEGlAgEiLpp

Comment: Great! thankyou so much @LionelT it will very helpful to me. i will be touch with yu if any issues occure..

Answer (score 0):

There have been numerous tricks and hacks to accomplish this over the years. Some are better than others, depending on the shape you are after. Some used CSS border colors and thicknesses on specific borders of elements, others have used images to get the effect.

**With CSS3, and the shape you are showing, I think you want to use "perspective" or perhaps "skew" or even "rotate".**

Here's a good listing of the various ways CSS3 can help here:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

You can read all about perspective here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective

Here's a simpler example of perspecive to perhaps get started with: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_perspective1

And here's a quick example (you'll still need to fuss with the numbers a bit to get it more precise):

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".menuItem");
  
  for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i){
  
     divs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
       this.parentElement.children[0].style.backgroundColor = "#090";
       this.parentElement.children[1].style.backgroundColor = "#090";       
     });  
    
     divs[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
       this.parentElement.children[0].style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
       this.parentElement.children[1].style.backgroundColor = "#fff";       
     });      
  }

  
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
}

#menuItem { width: 300px; }

#mainDiv {

 height:28px;
 width:120px;
 padding-left:5px;
 padding-top:10px;
}

#skewedDiv {
    width: 30px;
  
    -ms-transform: skewX(-25deg) translate(1px, 5px) rotate(-25deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-25deg) translate(1px, 5px) rotate(-25deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skewX(-25deg) translate(1px, 5px) rotate(-25deg); /* Standard syntax */
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuItem">
  <div class="menuItem" id="skewedDiv"></div>
  <div class="menuItem" id="mainDiv">Fire Solution</div>
</div>
```

NOTE: The use of vendor prefixes is useful for older browsers, but there is strong support for CSS transformations at this point.

Comment: Why have you used `skewX` combined with `rotate` instead of a simple `skewY`? Why haven't you reproduced the values for the IE/Safari users (since they're going to have a very different visual result)?

Comment: You can use `skewX` and `skewY` instead of the single `skew(x, y)` - that's a matter of choice. As for compatibility --  I'm still updating the code and haven't gotten to that yet. :)